# Chrome Extension: log in in options page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i'm trying to make a chrome extension and I need the have an options page where the user is able to login. this way the extension knows who he is and can retrieve specific data from a server.
I'm not sure how to do this. Any one has a tutorial page or, better yet, a sample code?

thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

A number of extensions use OAuth or OpenID for authentication. There is a tutorial for OAuth on [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html). You could also just use a username/password and make a XHR request to validate them. It really depends on the site and what authentication methods it offers.

Answer (score 0):

You need an authentication engine... In other words you need to have a backend for your chrome extension which handles logging in and logging out. This is extremely easy to do. You can use a backend as a service if it's a small project (look at Parse or Firebase) or write your own backend using a framework like Ruby on Rails.

http://rubyonrails.org/; https://www.parse.com/; https://www.firebase.com/

Answer (score -2):

Options pages are well documented on the [official docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/options.html), including sample code.

Comment: Iknow what an options page is.. That wasn't really my question. :) I was asking specifically how to make one that can login to some server.